# como obtener todos los radio button sin usar getElementbyName ni getElementById

Tags: javascript, get

quiero obtener la respuesta de mis radio button a traves de los input type radio(seria el elemento en comun que tienen) sin usar  getElementbyName ni getElementById pues, tendria que cambiar los name y no puedo hacerlo. les muestro mi codigo, espero y le agradeceria mucho su ayuda. en el codigo de javascript, la funcion alertarespuesta1 es donde intento obtener la info de los radio button

```
<body id= "contenidochilena">
  <h2 id= "izquierda">Lee atentamente las siguientes preguntas y marca la alternativa correcta:</h2>
  <center>
  <h1>1. ¿Cuándo fue la Primera Junta de Gobierno?:</h1>
  <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa4" value="El mes pasado"> El mes pasado<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa4" id = "correcta4" value="18 de septiembre de 1810"> 18 de septiembre de 1810<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa4" value="18 de octubre de 1910">18 de octubre de 1910<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa4" value="10 de septiembre de 1810">10 de septiembre de 1810
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" id= "respuesta4" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>

  <h1>2. ¿En qué ciudad se encuentra actualmente el Congreso?:</h1>
    <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa5" value="Santiago"> Santiago<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa5" value="Chiloé"> Chiloé<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa5" id= "correcta5" value="Valparaíso">Valparaíso<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa5" value="Madrid">Madrid
    </p>
  <p><input type="submit" id= "respuesta5" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>
  <div> 
    <h1>3. ¿Quién fue la primera presidenta mujer en Chile?:</h1>
    <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa6" value="Gabriela Mistral"> Gabriela Mistral<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa6" value="Elisa Loncón"> Elisa Loncón<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa6" id = "correcta6" value="Michelle Bachelet">Michelle Bachelet<br>
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa6" value="Gladys Marín">Gladys Marín
    </p>
      <p><input type="submit" id= "respuesta6" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>
</div> 
          <button id="puntajechilena">puntaje total</button>
          <button onclick="location.href='index.html'">Volver a jugar</button>
    </center>
 
</div>
<script src="scriptchile.js"></script>
</body>
```

javascript

```
function alertarespuesta1 (){
  //con el addEventListener se hace un "cambio"
    window.addEventListener('change', function () {
    // obtenemos los elementos con name = "alternativa"
    var alternativas = document.querySelectorAll("input type radio");
     
   
    for (i = 0; i < alternativas.length; i++) {
        if (alternativas[i].checked) {
            alert("Has seleccionado a "+ alternativas[i].value);
            }
    }
}, false);
  }
alertarespuesta1();
```

Comment: En realidad el selector del querySelectorAll sería `'input[type="radio"]'` no `'input type radio'`. Puedes usar también `input[name=alternativa5]:checked` para obtener el de alternativa5 que fue seleccionado, ahorrándote el `for`.

Comment: puse eso pero ahora se repite la alerta value= el mes pasado en la alternativa value= "santiago" y asi sucesivamente. espero tu ayuda, gracias por lo anterior

Comment: Disculpa, pero es que no me queda nada claro lo que quieres. ¿Quieres una alerta cada vez que se de click? ¿Algo como [esto](https://codepen.io/jaimemenendez/pen/abqRLBV)?

Comment: muchisimas gracias, de verdad, ahora si funciona!! pero no entiendo porque. si no es mucha molestia me explicarias porque con tu codigo solo aparece una alerta y con el mio aparecian todas.

Comment: Porque en lugar de agregar el evento al input radio, tú se lo estás agregando a la ventana completa (window). Entonces, nada más haya un cambio, las alertas de cada radio se van a disparar. En cambio yo, le agrego el evento a cada radio individual, y solo se disparará cuando se de click en ese radio.